# Can't delete status with Facebook app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth

```
$ curl -X DELETE "https://graph.facebook.com/637556776_241445419214379?access_token={token}"

{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#200) This post wasn't created by the application"}}
```

The access token is freshly generated, and has *all* the permissions assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.remove/ :
>
> "your application may only remove posts that were created through it"

The legacy API's documentation specifies this; Its not really clear in Graph API's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, you can't have an application editing a user status :   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/

Comment: You can't edit. You can however delete a user status (if it was created through your app).